# Optimization: Can I avoid a dynamic allocation of a vector in this loop?

Tags: c++, optimization, memory

I would like to understand whether I can avoid a dynamic allocation of a vector in the following code:

```cpp
#include <vector>
int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec;
    while (predictate()) {
        int curr_size = foo();
        vec.resize(curr_size);
        bar(vec);
    }
};
```

`perf` shows that about 30% of the time within the loop are spent for the function `vec.resize(curr_size)`. Is is possible to eradicate time spent resizing the vector without changing the API of the functions involved in the program too much? I could think of the following approaches:

- Using a `std::array` instead of a `std::vector` as I believe it avoids dynamic reallocation.
- The upper bound of the size of `vec` is known. I could thus can allocate the memory only once and use `curr_size` as an end point inside `bar`.
- I wondered if [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) allows resetting the end-of-vector pointer but I couldn't find a way to do that. Is that possible?

What steps could be taken to avoid spending time on resizing the vector? I have no experience with such optimization and would be glad to hear more educated suggestions. I am grateful for any hints or suggestions!

Comment: Look into [`std::vector::reserve()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve), used before the loop.

Comment: can you show the real code? `resize` shouldnt be that expensive if you `reserve` enough up front

Comment: `resize` never shrinks the capacity of the vector.  That means the "time wasted" should actually be time spent growing the vector only, which you'll have to do if you don't know what the final size will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reallocations are expensive. You can avoid any reallocations to happen inside the loop if you reserve enough space upfront:

```
#include <vector>
int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec;

    vec.reserve( max_size );   // reserve enough space

    while (predictate()) {
        int curr_size = foo();
        vec.resize(curr_size);   // no rellocations when curr_size <= max_size
        bar(vec);
    }
};
```

If you can change `bar` to take iterators, then no resizing is necessary (still assuming you know max value of `foo()`):

```
    std::vector<int> vec( max_size );
    while (predictate()) {
        int curr_range = foo();
        bar(vec.begin(), vec.begin() + curr_range);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply - That is very helpful to me! Is there maybe any information on the [function description](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) on cpprefence indicating that no reallocation occur when `curr_size` < `max_size`. I have been trying to read the documentation for some time but couldn't infer this.

Comment: @fabian i remeber that it isnt mentioned explicitly but its implicit due to other requirements. I'll add more to the answer when I find it

Comment: @fabian The [`resize()` page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) says: "*Complexity: Linear in the difference between the current size and count.  **Additional complexity possible due to reallocation if capacity is less than count**.*" Also read the [main vector page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), which has more information about reallocations.

Comment: @fabian its in the notes: "Vector capacity is never reduced when resizing to smaller size because that would invalidate all iterators, rather than only the ones that would be invalidated by the equivalent sequence of pop_back() calls.", though I would have to search for iterator invalidation rules. When new size if greater then capacity, obviously all iterators can be invalidated.